# How to set a pixel in a bitmap to white color?

Tags: c#

This does not work:

```
Color col;
objBitmap = new Bitmap(Resource1.im);
col = Color.FromName("White");
// Perform an operation on the Color value here.
objBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, col);
```

When I load the image to a picture box control, it is still black (the pixel that should be white).

EDIT:

This is how I load the bitmap to a picture box control after editing it:

```
objBitmap.Save(Resource1.im.ToString());

this.pictureBox2.Image = ResizeBitmap(Resource1.im, 100, 100);

objBitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: Your `Save` call is _totally_ wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably showing the wrong Bitmap in the PictureBox.

In the debugger's Watch window, right-click on `objBitmap` and on `somePictureBox.Image` and click Make Object ID.
If the two objects have different IDs, you're displaying the wrong image.

**EDIT**: `Bitmap.Save` takes a *filename*.
Your code creates a file named `Bitmap` in the current directory.
Change it to `pictureBox2.Image = ResizeBitmap(objBitmap, 100, 100);`

ResX files are readonly; you cannot modify the stored Bitmap at runtime.
Instead, you can put the modified image in a static `Bitmap` field.  (And make sure not to dispose it until you don't need it anymore)

---

Note, by the way, that you can write

```
Color col = Color.White;
```

Comment: Maybe I am loading the bitmap to the picture box incorrectly. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is a good idea to modify a `Bitmap` thatis some kind of resource. I'd `Clone` it to be safe. That being said, I could not reproduce a problem.

```
Bitmap objBitmap = (Bitmap)Resource1.im.Clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what col is set to? In particular what the alpha component is set to?
Ie. You might be adding transparent white?

Comment: Alpha component is set to 255. What should it be set to?

Comment: Which makes sense: why would Microsoft set it to transparent? What about the other components? Are they all zero (=black) or all 255 (=white)?